# Cast C++ PyTorch Tensor to Python PyTorch Tensor

Tags: c++, boost, pytorch, pyobject

For a project that I am working on, I need to call from C++ a Python function, which has as input a PyTorch Tensor. While searching for a way to achieve this, I found that using a function named [**THPVariable_Wrap**](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/63214b572b6a18f7328687ca69420f0be0eaaaa9/torch/csrc/autograd/python_variable.cpp#L64-L76) (Information I have found [link 1](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/pytorch-tensors-from-c-to-python/36918) and [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66024389/how-to-convert-pytorch-tensor-to-c-torchtensor-vice-versa)) could transform a C++ Pytorch Tensor to a PyObject, which can be used as input for the call to the Python function. However, I have tried importing this function by including the header file directly in my code, but this will always return the error *LNK2019*, when calling the function, with the following description:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) struct _object * __cdecl THPVariable_Wrap(class at::TensorBase)" (_*imp*?THPVariable_Wrap@@YAPEAU_object@@VTensorBase@at@@@Z) referenced in function main pythonCppTorchExp   C:\Users\MyName\source\repos\pythonCppTorchExp\pythonCppTorchExp\example-app.obj    1

I believe the problem is in how I import the **THPVariable_Wrap** function in my C++ file. However, I am still not that skilled with C++ and the information on this is limited. Besides Pytorch, I am also using Boost for calling Python and I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 (v142), with C++ 14. I posted the code I used below.

#### C++ File

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <Python.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fstream> 
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <torch/torch.h>

#include <torch/csrc/autograd/python_variable.h> /* The header file where  */

namespace python = boost::python;
namespace fs = boost::filesystem;

using namespace std;


int main() {
    string module_path = "Path/to/python/folder";

    Py_Initialize();

    torch::Tensor cppTensor = torch::ones({ 100 });
    PyRun_SimpleString(("import sys\nsys.path.append(\"" + module_path + "\")").c_str());

    python::object module = python::import("tensor_test_file");
    python::object python_function = module.attr("tensor_equal");

    PyObject* castedTensor = THPVariable_Wrap(cppTensor) /* This function call creates the error.*/;

    python::handle<> boostHandle(castedTensor);
    python::object inputTensor(boostHandle);
    python::object result = python_function(inputTensor);

    bool succes = python::extract<bool>(result);
    if (succes) {
        cout << "The tensors match" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "The tensors do not match" << endl;
    }
}
```

#### Python File

```python
import torch

def tensor_equal(cppTensor):
    pyTensor = torch.ones(100)
    areEqual = cppTensor.equal(pyTensor)
    return areEqual
```

Answer (score 1):

This is linker problem. You probably have to link **libtorch.python.so**. It can be located in place like */opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_python.so*. Or where you have your libtorch installed.